# Show the fourier transform of a function satisfies a differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, complex-integration

On page 27 of *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension*, it seems like Mattila makes the claim that when $\Psi(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$, then $\Psi = \widehat{\Psi}$. This is said to be true because both expressions satisfy the differential equation $f'(x)=-2\pi x f(x)$ with initial condition $f(0)=1$. I see why $\Psi$ satisfies this equation, but why is it that

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\pi x^2-2 \pi i x t} dx = -2 \pi x \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\pi x^2-2 \pi i x t} dx?$$

Is this an issue with taking the derivative of a complex function?

Comment: The $x$ cannot be taken out of the integral. What you really need to prove is that $$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\Psi} = -2\pi t \hat{\Psi}$$

Comment: Use integration by parts

Comment: You don't really need to know that it's a Gaussian, just that it satisfies that differential equation. Then integrate by parts. For that matter (disregarding constants), an equation $\Psi'=x\Psi$ itself stays the same under Fourier transform, namely (up to constants), it becomes $t\hat{\Psi}=\hat{\Psi}'$, since Fourier transform interchanges derivative and multiplication by $x$...

Comment: Let $\phi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ be a Schwartz function. Define its Fourier transform by
$$\hat{\phi}(\xi)=\mathcal{F}(\phi)(\xi)=\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(x)e^{2\pi i\xi x}\mathrm dx$$
You now need only show that 
$$\hat{\phi}'(\xi)=-2\pi\xi~\hat{\phi}(\xi)$$
This is very easy. All you need is the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi x^2-2\pi i xt}dx=-2\pi i\int_{\mathbb{R}}xe^{-\pi x^2-2\pi i xt}dx$